# R: Convert date+time strings like this: "11feb2022 00:00:00" into an appropriate date-time format?

Tags: r

I've tried:

```
test <- "11feb2022 00:00:00"
as.POSIXct(test, format="%dd%mm%YYYY")
[1] NA

test <- "11feb2022 00:00:00"
as.POSIXct(test, format="%d%m%Y")
[1] NA
```

but I would like some hints on where to go from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `%b` (Abbreviated month name in the current locale) instead of `%m` (which stands for 'month' as decimal number).  Also, if the Time values are important, use `%T` short form for `%H:%M:%S`

```
as.POSIXct(test, format="%d%b%Y %T")
[1] "2022-02-11 CST"
```

Comment: thanks. how do I keep the hours, minutes, and seconds? And how do I change the Timezone to something else? E.g.:

"2022-02-11 00:00:00 EAT"

and how do I do a comparison of this date? For example, in pseudocode: 

"2022-02-12 01:24:12 EAT" > "2022-02-11 00:00:00 EAT" 

[1] TRUE

Comment: @user2205916 It is already there.  It is just that your example shows a value of '00:00:00'.  If it is instead any other value, it would be showed. You can use the `tz` option in `as.POSIXct` to change the `tz`

Comment: @user2205916 i..e `as.POSIXct(test, format="%d%b%Y %T", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: @user2205916 For the comparison i.e. `test1 <- "12feb2022 01:24:12"; as.POSIXct(test1, format="%d%b%Y %T", tz = "UTC") > as.POSIXct(test, format="%d%b%Y %T", tz = "UTC")#
[1] TRUE`